# Importing data from a CSV file — a string is being converted to a number

Tags: import, text, csv-format

I'm very much a newbie, so please forgive any errors or stupidity.

I have a csv file named `csvfile`. Its, contents confirmed by me, by looking at the contents in a text viewer are:

```
234GJ,9060G,8096F,4162J
```

When I read this file into any other software -- say, R, Stata, or Excel, it results in four text items.

When I read it into Mathematica using

```
Import["csvfile", "CSV"]
```

I get a list that is a mix of strings and a number; after `Flatten` it becomes

```
{"234GJ", "9060G", 8096, "4162J"}
```

Can anyone tell my why this is happening?

Answer (score 7):

`Import["csvfile", "CSV", "Numeric" -> False]` will stop it from interpreting elements as numbers, this can be found in [CSV](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/CSV.html)

Comment: Thank you!  I was searching on things such as "text to numbers" and "format" and not getting anywhere. Quick supplemental! Why does F at the end convert it to a number?

Comment: @mjchalk to be honest, I do not know what "F" means in this case, but at least it does not mean floating point number, because you can get integers from `123F` and lower case "f" does nothing. The only documented formats are `xxxD/dxxx` and `xxxE/exxx` meaning exponential.

Comment: I have the answer!  It is to be found in "CurrencyTokens". F is treated as a currency and by default is skipped on entry of a number (same for £, $ and even c apparently).  So for data integrity purposes when importing using CSV it is best invoke "CurrencyTokens" -> None as an option.  But thanks for your help on this.

Comment: @mjchalk thanks! It turns out that I missed the option part of the docs.